# Update Table from Specific Select Statement SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
IDs     ZoneID     ChildID     ParentID
--------------------------------------------
null    1          36000       36000
null    1          36000       36000
null    2          37000       37000
```

I want to update the `IDs` column with the following `select` statement:

```
SELECT a.ZONEID FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN Table1 b on a.ParentID = b.ChildID
```

So, the `IDs` column will be filled with the result of the `select` statement above.

The result should be:

```
IDs     ZoneID     ChildID     ParentID
--------------------------------------------
1       1          36000       36000
1       1          36000       36000
2       2          37000       37000
```

I tried the following tsql:

```
Update Table1
set IDs = (SELECT a.ZONEID FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN Table1 b on a.ParentID = b.ChildID)
```

But error appears when I execute it. Too many argument result, something like that.

Please advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
Update Table1
    set IDs = (SELECT a.ZONEID FROM Table1 a WHERE a.ParentID = Table1.ChildID);
```

You don't need a `JOIN` in the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use join with a UPDATE query

```
Update Table1
set IDs = a.ZONEID 
FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN Table1 b on a.ParentID = b.ChildID
```